# Can I overwinter this Alocasia bulb

Tags: overwintering, bulbs, aroid

From the moment I saw this club-shaped thing sticking out from the topsoil, I knew it was a bulb or a corm. This one accidentally broke-off, but luckily I have at-least one more around the plant which I will keep attached to the mother plant till spring. My question, if this broke-off, is it possible to keep it dormant till spring and then plant it? Do I have to keep in a cold place (like the upper compartment of the fridge), or should I plant it immediately?[image]

**UPDATE** -- A week has passed. I took it out of the drawer. Unfortunately, the corm was already brown and shriveled. I guess it would have never survived if I kept it till spring. Planting the corm as soon as it broke-off may have been the only way, and it would not survive otherwise.

Comment: *Alocasia* is a tropical plant so it is unlikely to need a cold dormant period. I would just plant it, and wait. Plants don't become extinct in the wild just because they get broken when they are tiny.

Comment: Yes, I know it's a tropical that does not go dormant normally, but I think it's outside its climatic zone and it may be too cold. Otherwise I would just plant it as is. Winter this year is a bit too warm, but a cold wind may hit anytime and I don't know for how long.